# what is the difference between Qt stylesheet and QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

what is the easier way to handle stylesheet codes and which one is better to use qt style sheet or QML?

Comment: These are different things. QML is a meta-language for designing interface, qss is a language for describing the visual style of your QWidgets.

Comment: Do you mean the .ui files ? QML is much better, it is the future. Go for QML and don't think. Of course your app logic has to be made in C++, only the presentation layer should be written in QML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are two very different things.

1. Qt StyleSheets are similar to the web technology Cascading Style Sheets.
   They are way to change aspect of visualization of QtWidget elements using text snippets, the style sheet code.
   They can be applied and changed dynamically at runtime, for specific widgets or globally.
   Essentially they are an alternative to implementing a custom `QStyle`, easier but also with a reduced set of customization capabilities.
2. QML is a declarative language, used with a "QML engine" to create trees of objects of `QObject` based classes.
   Depending on the modules used to provide these classes, the resulting object tree can a graphic user interface, e.g. when using `QtQuick` or `BlackBerry10 Cascades`
   Of course, what such an UI can do visualization or effect wise depends on which modules are used.
   Similar to stylesheets, QML code is also usually loaded at runtime.